# Redirect domain.com/abcd to domain.com/mypage.aspx/abcd

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm trying to create an IIS redirect from

domain.com/abcd 
to
domain.com/mypage.aspx/abcd

abcd can be any set of characters or numbers (abcd, ab, ab4c, etc..)
mypage.aspx will always be mypage.aspx

I find many ways of doing this backwards but for some reason I can't get this to work.  Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this question has been unanswered for so long as it's quite simple to do:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to mypage.aspx" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain\.com$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/mypage\.aspx/" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/mypage.aspx/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Made it dynamic, also added exception for existing files / directories, otherwise static content would not work anymore.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my question.  abcd can be anything.  mypage.aspx will always be mypage.aspx.  Do you have a solution for a dynamic abcd.